# How do I load xibs by reusing a single viewcontroller and handle the memory warnings?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller

I am making a game for the iPhone that consists of 4 mini games. Each mini game is a standalone xib. Each game consists of its own menu and the game levels. You go to the main menu and select which game you want to load.

This is how I am currently loading each xib.

**MainGameViewController.h**

```
@interface MainGameViewController : UIViewController {

    UIViewController *currentView;
    int currentViewId;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *currentView;
- (void)displayView:(int)intNewView;
@end
```

**MainGameViewController.m**

```
@implementation MainGameViewController

@synthesize currentView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    currentView = [[LogoScreen alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:currentView.view];
}

- (void)displayView :(int)intNewView
{
    currentViewId = intNewView;
    currentView = nil;
    [currentView release];
    switch (intNewView) {
        case SCR_GAME1:
            currentView = [[Game1View alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME1LEVEL:
            currentView = [[Game1LevelView alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME2:
            currentView = [[Game2View alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME2LEVEL:
            currentView = [[Game2LevelView alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME3:
            currentView = [[Game3View alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME3LEVEL:
            currentView = [[Game3LevelView alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME4:
            currentView = [[Game4View alloc] init];
            break;
        case SCR_GAME4LEVEL:
            currentView = [[Game4LevelView alloc] init];
            break;       
        default:
            currentView = [[MainView alloc] init];
            break;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:currentView.view];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [currentView release];
    currentView = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And this is how the levels are launched.
**Game1View.m**

```
@implementation Game1View

-init {
    if (self == [super init]) {

        MainGameAppDelegate *appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        isSoundOn = (appdelegate.gvar.soundstate == 1);
        gamestate = GAME_STATUS_START;
    }
    return self;
}
...
...
- (void)launchgame {

    MainGameAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.gvar.currentId = objectid;
    [appDelegate displayView:SCR_GAME1LEVEL_GAME];

}

- (void)returnToMain {
    MainGameAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate displayView:SCR_MAIN];
}

@end
```

**MainGameAppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation MainGameAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (void) displayView:(int)intNewView {
    [viewController displayView:intNewView];
}
@end
```

Currently I'm getting memory warnings when I keep switching between the views and then the app crashes. 
My question is, is this the correct way to load these views? I've released everything that I've allocated for the duration of the game's lifespan and I am now at a loss at what's hogging up the memory. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're not releasing your game views properly, since your code will actually set currentView to nil before calling release, meaning you'll be leaking every game view created.

```
- (void)displayView :(int)intNewView
{
    currentViewId = intNewView;
    currentView = nil;
    [currentView release];
    switch (intNewView) {
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
- (void)displayView :(int)intNewView
{
    currentViewId = intNewView;
    [currentView release];
    currentView = nil;
    switch (intNewView) {
```

Also, you naming your view controllers "View"s is confusing. Consider giving them more descriptive names, like xxxController.

Edit 1:

You also need to make sure the old game is removed from the view hierarchy before you release it. Call [currentView.view removeFromSuperview] before releasing your view to remove it first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think you mean [currentView.view removeFromSuperview]; but if I add that before [currentView release];
it'll just cause one of my xibs to have a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when deallocating.

Comment: Since you have previously added the subview, it's normal to have to remove the view via removeFromSuperview. Try turning on XCode's zombies to see where the extra release has occurred.